# Yii2 Update records resulting from query

Tags: mysql, select, yii2

I need to update `month_no` fields of the records resulting from a select query using some variables passed from controller but every field is written with the same value.

These are the variables:

```
    $id_calc = 27
    $from_y = "2013-05-01"
    $to_y = "2015-11-31"
```

The table result:

```
   id   id_paid   year_ref     month_no
    1        26      2012         12
    2        26      2013         12
    4        27      2013         12  (should be 8)
    5        27      2014         12
    6        27      2015         12  (should be 11)
```

This is model:

```
 public function CorrectTable($id_calc, $from_y, $to_y)
    {  
        $connection = Yii::$app->db;
        $query = "SELECT * FROM my_table where id_paid='$id_calc'";
        $data = $connection->createCommand($query)->queryAll();
        // calculate no. of month first and last year
        $month_no_begin = (13 - date("m",strtotime($from_y)));   
        $month_no_end = (date("m",strtotime($to_y)));
        // 
        foreach($data as $row) 
        {
          $id = $row['id'];
          // calculate number of month per year
          if ($row['year_ref'] = date("Y",strtotime($from_y))) 
          {
            $month_no = $month_no_begin;
          } elseif  ($row['year_ref'] = date("Y",strtotime($to_y))) 
          {
            $month_no = $month_no_end;
          } else
          {
            $month_no = 12;
          }
            Yii::$app->db->createCommand()
            ->update('my_table', ['month_no' => $month_no], ['id' => $id])
            ->execute();
        }
```

I tried to put the above code in controller with the same result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A careless mistake once I had made before. You should use `==` or `===` in the `if` statement to test equal condition, instead of `=`

```
public function CorrectTable($id_calc, $from_y, $to_y)
{  
    $connection = Yii::$app->db;
    $query = "SELECT * FROM my_table where id_paid='$id_calc'";
    $data = $connection->createCommand($query)->queryAll();
    // calculate no. of month first and last year
    $month_no_begin = (13 - date("m",strtotime($from_y)));   
    $month_no_end = (date("m",strtotime($to_y)));
    // 
    foreach($data as $row) 
    {
        $id = $row['id'];

        // use `==` instead of `=`
        if ($row['year_ref'] == date("Y",strtotime($from_y))) 
        {
            $month_no = $month_no_begin;
        }

        // use `==` instead of `=`
        elseif ($row['year_ref'] == date("Y",strtotime($to_y))) 
        {
            $month_no = $month_no_end;
        }
        else
        {
            $month_no = 12;
        }

        Yii::$app->db->createCommand()
            ->update('my_table', ['month_no' => $month_no], ['id' => $id])
            ->execute();
    }
}
```

Comment: this answer  is wrong and don't result the OP problem

Comment: @scaisEdge You have to admit that this OP's problem was caused by using the wrong operator. I don't think the OP would have any problem in the condition logic. But you are right, should I delete my answer or should I change my answer?

Comment: You answer  solve the problem with the worng use fo = / == in if but don't solve the logic for OP  .. is a good suggestion but nor the right answer

Comment: @scaisEdge Could you please tell me what I'm wrong?

Comment: @scaisEdge Thank you! Frankly, I like the style you dealing with things.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/148709/discussion-between-paul-and-scaisedge).

Answer (score 1):

our if ... esleif ... else sequence seems not logig 
as you done the else if is never executed

so you should change the condition this way  the e

```
 foreach($data as $row) 
    {
        $id = $row['id'];

        // assigne default value
        $month_no = 12;

        // check for month_begin
        if ($row['year_ref'] == date("Y",strtotime($from_y))) 
        {
            $month_no = $month_no_begin;
        }

        //check for month_end    
        if ($row['year_ref'] == date("Y",strtotime($to_y))) 
        {
            $month_no = $month_no_end;
        }


        Yii::$app->db->createCommand()
            ->update('my_table', ['month_no' => $month_no], ['id' => $id])
            ->execute();
    }
```

Comment: Thank you @scaisEdge. It works and the code is cleaner

Comment: You do solve the problem of the OP's. In order to match the result of the OP's, you totally change the style. By the way, the if statements in your code will constantly be executed twice, and `$month_no = $month;` also might be. Compare with with the OP's, you answer actually brings additional overhead.

Comment: @gdel   ... i'm sorry but the right answer is the answer of Paul  .. so you should not mark my answer as accepted  but mark the  paul one .. ( the my previuos commen was wrong ..